# Replace whitespace with hyphen in URL

Tags: php, get, mysqli, seo, isset

I am trying to create a SEO friendly site. At the moment the page works because the id is shown in the URL so like `product.php?id=4` however I want to replace `ID` with the `product_name`, but the value to this can contain whitespaces, so the URL looks like `product.php?product_name=fence%20panel` but this doesn't work because I use this GET variable to look up product details in my database, and when it does it thinks it is one word so no product is found. So what I think I need is a variable that adds a hyphen so `product.php?product_name=fence-panel` but also a variable that changes this hyphen back to a space. Correct me if I'm wrong

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
$id = $_GET['id']; 
//Get the product if exists 
//if no product then give a message 
$sql = mysqli_query($myNewConnection, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1"); 
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
if ($productCount > 0) { 
    //get product details 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $product_name = $row["product_name"]; 
        $price = $row["price"]; 
        $details = $row["details"]; 
        $category = $row["category"]; 
        $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"])); 
        $_SESSION['product_price_array'] = $price; 
    } 
} else{ 
    echo "No Product in the system"; 
    exit(); 
}
```

Comment: this is hacker friendly

Comment: @marabutt care to elaborate?

Comment: open to an sql injection

Comment: @marabutt As it is or if I change it?

Comment: As it is. See the line that begins with `$sql`.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection via `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rawurlencode()` and `rawurldecode()`. See [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.rawurlencode.php) for examples. It won't add hyphens but it will do what you want. To add hyphens you could try doing the following after encoding: `$str = str_replace('-', '%2D', $str);`. And you should probably do it once again and swap the two first parameters before decoding, too!